# Nginx: Reverse proxy for Websocket with Passthrough TLS

Tags: nginx, websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a backend websocket server that requires TLS (`wss://mybackendserver.com`) for connections. It cannot be connected to via `ws://`.

I would like to create an nginx reverse proxy (`myproxy.com`) that forwards incoming connections (also with TLS, i.e. `wss://myproxy.com`) to the backend server. Note that the certificate for the backend server also includes `myproxy.com`, and **therefore I would like to do TLS pass-through and not need to include separate certificates on the proxy.**

How can I achieve this? I've tried the following nginx config:

```
http {
    ...

    upstream websocket {
        ip_hash;
        server mybackendserver:443;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://websocket;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try `wscat -c wss://myproxy.com`, I get the following error:

> error: write EPROTO FC5B0000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:355:

I have also tried using `stream`:

```
stream {
    upstream websocket {
        server mybackendserver:443;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass websocket;
        proxy_next_upstream on;
    }
}
```

But `wscat` on this one gives me:

> error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

As to why this is necessary, I have a Websocket API Gateway on AWS, but I need a static IP for it and that's not possible using AWS tools. So, I need an nginx proxy with a static IP.